# c# determine how long the computer has been to sleep for & then convert this to an integer

Tags: c#, datetime

How do I convert this the time the computer has been to sleep for (here called 'offTime') into an integer (in terms of minutes)?

```
   `DateTime timeOnSleep = DateTime.Now;`  
  `Application.SetSuspendState(PowerState.Suspend, true, true);`

  `DateTime timeOnWake = DateTime.Now;`

  `System.TimeSpan offTime = timeOnWake - timeOnSleep;`
```

Comment: The best way to find out is to run the code...

Comment: `Math.Round(offTime.TotalMinutes, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);`

Comment: Thanks @GeoffBattye, I now understand exactly what to do with your snippet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TimeSpan time = timeOnWake - timeOnSleep;
var hours = time.TotalHours;
```

Comment: Thanks Gjohn.  The 2nd line, though, gives me the error that it cannot be used as a statement.  Any thoughts?  Cheers

Comment: @N.Soong - It is important to note that the TotalHours property returns the value in the form of a double. You will need to round up or down as you see fit and then convert the value into an int.